# What is the benefit for Collections.singleton() to return a Set instead of a Collection?

Tags: java, collections

The [`Collections.singleton()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-) returns a `Set` with that single argument instead of a `Collection`.

Why is that so? From what I can see, apart from `Set` being a subtype of `Collection`, I can see no advantage... Is this only because `Set` extends `Collection` anyway so there is no reason not to?

And yes, there is also [`Collections.singletonList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-) but this is another matter since you can access random elements from a `List` with `.get()`...

Comment: The only benefit I can think of would be that methods that accept a `Set` would not accept a `Collections.singleton()` had it returned a simple `Collection`.

Comment: @Slanec indeed... Whereas methods accepting a `Collection` will happily accept a `Set` as well...

Comment: Possibly because the word "singleton" in mathematics implies a set.

Comment: Because a collection of one single element is a set, by definition.

Comment: @immibis my maths are not to that level :/ Would you be so kind as to provide a link clarifying the concepts?

Comment: @fge It's the definition, nothing particularly deep. First sentence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%28mathematics%29 for example - "In mathematics, a singleton, also known as a unit set, is a set with exactly one element."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a "benefit" or "advantage" per se?  It's just the method that returns a singleton `Set`, and happens to be the default implementation when you want a singleton `Collection` as well, since a singleton `Collection` happens to be a mathematical set as well.

Comment: I didn't really go as deep as the mathematical defintion of a set but yes, that is also true. In fact, the benefit really seems to be that since in this particular case a `Collection` and a `Set` are basically equivalent, why not return a `Set`? After all, had there been a difference, we would probably have had `.singletonCollection()` and `.singletonSet()`...

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your answer correctly fge , but in fact there are Collections.singleton() [Set], and Collections.singletonList() [List] there's also Collections.singletonMap() available! Maybe in '15 it wasn't :-)

Comment: @funder7 these came in Java 1.3 in 2000 :)

Answer (score 21):

## Immutable

The benefit is found in the first adjective read in [that JavaDoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-): *immutable*.

There are times when you are working with code that demands a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (or `List`, etc.). In your own context you may have a strict need for only a single item. To accomplish your own goal of enforcing the rule of single-item-only while needing to present that item in a set, use a `Set` implementation that forbids you from adding more than one item.

“Immutable” on [`Collections::singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-) means that, once created, the resulting `Set` object is guaranteed to have one, and only one item. Not zero, and not more than one.  No more can be added. The one item cannot be removed.

For example, imagine your code is working with an `Employee` object representing the CEO (Chief Executive Officer) of your company. Your code is explicitly dealing with the CEO only, so you know there can be only one such `Employee` object at a time, always one CEO exactly. Yet you want to leverage some existing code that creates a report for a specified collection of `Employee` objects. By using `Collection.singleton` you are guaranteed that your own code does not mistakenly have other than one single employee, while still being able to pass a `Set`.

```
Set< Employee > ceo = Collections.singleton( new Employee( "Tim Cook" ) ) ;  // Always exactly one item in this context, only one CEO is possible.

ceo.add( … ) ;     // Fails, as the collection is immutable.
ceo.clear() ;      // Fails, as the collection is immutable.
ceo.remove( … ) ;  // Fails, as the collection is immutable.

someReport.processEmployees( ceo ) ;
```

## Java 9: `Set.of` & `List.of`

Java 9 and later offers new interface methods [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#of-E-) and [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-) to get the same effect, an immutable collection of a single element.

```
Set< Pet > pet = Set.of( someDog ) ;
```

Sibling `of` methods are overloaded to accept any number of  elements to be in the immutable collection, not just one element.

```
Set< Pet > pets = Set.of( someDog , someOtherDog , someCat ) ;
```

Comment: The question asks why a `Set` and not a `Collection`, not why have immutability.  And nothing about the `Set` interface provides immutability; it has a `remove()` method, for example.  Immutability for collections is 100% bolted on after-the-fact via exceptions.  `singletonList()` provides the same guarantees that `singleton()` does, via the same poor mechanism; there's no reason a `singletonCollection()` couldn't either.  It's a `Set` because it is, by definition, a set, and that interface is more useful than `Collection`.  That's it.

Answer (score 10):

I wondered the same thing and came across your question in my research. Here is my conclusion:

**Returning a `Set` keeps the Collections API clean.**

Here are the methods for getting a singleton Collection:

- `public static <T> Set<T> singleton(T o)`
- `public static <T> List<T> singletonList(T o)`
- `public static <K,V> Map<K,V> singletonMap(K key, V value)`

What if the API designers decided on having a `singletonSet` method and `singleton` method? It would look like this:

- `public static <T> Collection<T> singleton(T o)`
- `public static <T> Set<T> singletonSet(T o)`
- `public static <T> List<T> singletonList(T o)`
- `public static <K,V> Map<K,V> singletonMap(K key, V value)`

Is the `singleton` method really necessary? Let's think about why we would need some of these methods.

Think about when you would call `singletonList`? You probably have an API that requires `List` instead of `Collection` or `Set`. I will use this poor example:

```
public void needsList(List<?> list);
```

You can only pass a `List`. `needsList` hopefully needs the data indexed and is not arbitrarily requesting a `List` instead of a `Collection`.

However, you could also pass a `List` to a method that required any `Collection`:

```
public void needsAnyCollection(Collection<?> collection);
```

But if that is the case, then why use a `List`? A `List` has a more complicated API and involves storing indexes. Do you really need the indexes? Would a `Set` not suffice? I argue that you should use a `Set`, because `needsAnyCollection` does not care about the order.

This is where `singletonSet` really shines. You know that if the collection is of size 1 (singleton), then the data must be unique. **Collections of size 1 are coincidentally a Set.**

There is no need for a method which returns a singleton of type `Collection`, because it is accidentally a `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason singleton Collections exist is to provide a low memory collection if you know you are going to store 1 element and it is not going to be mutated. Especially in high volume services this can have significant impact due to garbage collection latency.

This applies for both `Set.of("1");` and `Collections.singleton("1");`

Since `Set` is a `Collection` already returning the more constrained contract is a good thing for users of the libraries. 
You get additional functionality without paying anything for it.

And you as a user should do the same as for any other API and library, you should store the least needed contract for it.

So if the only thing you'll ever need to do with the structure is to iterate in a loop I'd suggest to choose `Iterable` instead of using `List`, `Set` or `Collection`. Since a`Collection` is an `Iterable` this will work out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

Not all the lists are random access, just take a `LinkedList` (random access in the API, not in the implementation)as a counter-example. By the way I agree with Louis Wasserman, a `Set` simply makes sense because it is closer to the mathematical definition, it just feels natural.

Comment: Sorry, but the `List` contract _requires_ that you can `.get()` from any index. Whatever the big O implied, but this is a requirement. And that is, basically, random access to elements.

Comment: `ArrayList` implements `RandomAccess`, `LinkedList` does not. See the Javadoc. Random access implicitly means the cost of such a lookup is low, and most often constant. The Javadoc of `RandomAccess` explicitely mentions performance characteristics for determining whether a list should be marked as random access or not

Comment: I _know_ about the `RandomAccess` interface. The fact is that `List` provides a `.get(xx)` where `xx` is the index in the list -- regardless of whether that particular implementation implements `RandomAccess`!

Comment: If you don't trust me nore the Javadoc, at least trust Wikipedia : `As a rule the assumption is that each element can be accessed roughly as easily and efficiently as any other, no matter how many elements may be in the set, nor how many coordinates may be available for addressing the data.`. You are using your own definition of random access here.

Comment: Well, I know enough in this matter to take what Wikipedia says with a grain of salt, and do note that the `List` contract does not mandate that the big O of `.get()` be anything workable in practice ;)

Comment: Yeah, there is no condition on the complexity of `get`, but that does not make it a random access implementation. Just admit it, random access means fast access to any element of a set. Random Access Memory is faster than the memory on your disk which needs (at least older technologies) to rotate to reach a particular element. Random access in a video is the ability to access a frame from any other frame in opposition of frames that are encoded relatively to other frames. Random access ALWAYS means fast.

Comment: "random access means fast access" <-- NO. Random access only means that if you have a range to query, you can access an element of that range for whichever position; NOTHING, ever, is said about how _fast_ you can access that element. It can be O(1) or it can be anything else. How the implementation behaves does not apply; except that the JDK does define `RandomAccess` for O(1) accesses, but the interface itself is misnamed. Do not mistake the functionality with how it is implemented.

Comment: Well, for my last word : I get your point, it looks like a random access because you don't have to manually traverse all the list, but people would be really surprised of seeing something called random access performing badly at... random access. I don't think it is misnamed, random access always carries the implicit assumption that there is no cost in accessing an element over another

Comment: Random access is a pitiful name... It doesn't have anything to do with randomness by the way ;) it just means that you can access to any element of a range by specifying the range's start position + an offset. That is the case of RAM which stands for Random Access Memory. As that memory has very fast access to any position within a range, random access was generalised as "equally fast access to any element within the range".